# recursive std::stringstream and c_str

Tags: c++, std

I've implemented this straightforward function in order to empty a folder recursively (Xcode 5.1. Targeted platform iOS). The function calls itself for every sub-directory passing the path of the new directory.

But on the first recursive call the `path` parameter is zeroed after `opendir` is called again. The `path` parameter is now an empty string and I can't figure out why. The `stringstream buf` variable is not destroyed and AFAIK is not altered by `opendir` too.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
void emptyFolder(const char *path) 
{
   if (DIR *folder = opendir(path)) {
       while (struct dirent *entry = readdir(folder)) {
           if (strcmp(entry->d_name,".") == 0 ||
               strcmp(entry->d_name,"..") == 0)
               continue;

        std::stringstream buf;
        buf << path << '/' << entry->d_name;
        const char *filepath = buf.str().c_str();

           if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
               emptyFolder(filepath);
           remove(filepath)
       }
       closedir(folder);
    }
}
```

Comment: `const char *filepath = buf.str().c_str();` is bad. `buf.str()` is a temporary. It will die before the next statement, and its `.c_str()` will die with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As n.m said you need to copy the contents of the buf.str() or else you can pass the reference directly to the functions:

Option 1:

```
std::string filepath(buf.str());
if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
  emptyFolder(filepath.c_str());
remove(filepath.c_str())
```

Option 2:

```
if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
  emptyFolder(buf.str().c_str());
remove(buf.str().c_str())
```

I would also recommend that you use references to `std::string` rather than `const char*`. Use `c_str()` directly where you need to use an API that doesn't support string objects and avoid caching them (like in option 2).